# EC2 amazon run two server on two different sub domain

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2

Hi Currently I am running my application on port 80 on server
like `http://example.com`

now I want to run another application say on another domain sub domain on same `80` port like `http://abc.example.com`

how can I do this?

Comment: You can use Nginx as a reverse proxy, check out this link: https://www.garron.me/en/linux/nginx-reverse-proxy.html

Answer (score 0):

You'd do that by updating [CNAME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) DNS records. For example

```
http://example.com     <=> 123.123.123.123 // server 1 here
http://abc.example.com <=> 123.123.123.124 // server 1 or server 2 here
```

It doesn't really matter which port number you use